# Add to Array separate NSObject from Json Objective-C to save on UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, json, xcode, nsobject

I have a problem trying to create a NSMutableArray.
I have some information from Json, I got ID Properties from a NSObject and that information is sending separate from "property.propertyId" like this:

```
2016-10-13 16:58:25.225 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11635
2016-10-13 16:58:25.225 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10650
2016-10-13 16:58:25.225 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15228
2016-10-13 16:58:25.225 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11524
2016-10-13 16:58:25.225 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10465
2016-10-13 16:58:25.226 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 14487
2016-10-13 16:58:25.226 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11652
2016-10-13 16:58:25.226 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10585
2016-10-13 16:58:25.226 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 4871
2016-10-13 16:58:25.226 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 5130
2016-10-13 16:58:25.227 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15222
2016-10-13 16:58:25.227 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11901
2016-10-13 16:58:25.227 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10593
2016-10-13 16:58:25.227 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 14506
2016-10-13 16:58:25.227 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 14933
2016-10-13 16:58:25.228 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10677
2016-10-13 16:58:25.228 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 18462
2016-10-13 16:58:25.228 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10684
2016-10-13 16:58:25.228 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10608
2016-10-13 16:58:25.229 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11481
2016-10-13 16:58:25.229 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15404
2016-10-13 16:58:25.229 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11945
2016-10-13 16:58:25.230 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10250
2016-10-13 16:58:25.230 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11743
2016-10-13 16:58:25.230 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10631
2016-10-13 16:58:25.230 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 16066
2016-10-13 16:58:25.231 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10578
2016-10-13 16:58:25.231 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15391
2016-10-13 16:58:25.231 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 3669
2016-10-13 16:58:25.232 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15277
2016-10-13 16:58:25.232 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11440
2016-10-13 16:58:25.232 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15251
2016-10-13 16:58:25.232 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 14445
2016-10-13 16:58:25.232 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11722
2016-10-13 16:58:25.233 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10475
2016-10-13 16:58:25.233 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 14468
2016-10-13 16:58:25.233 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15386
2016-10-13 16:58:25.233 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11680
2016-10-13 16:58:25.233 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 18405
2016-10-13 16:58:25.233 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11610
2016-10-13 16:58:25.234 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 5209
2016-10-13 16:58:25.234 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10639
2016-10-13 16:58:25.234 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 10448
2016-10-13 16:58:25.234 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11551
2016-10-13 16:58:25.234 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 9185
2016-10-13 16:58:25.234 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15352
2016-10-13 16:58:25.235 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 18382
2016-10-13 16:58:25.235 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15241
2016-10-13 16:58:25.235 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11310
2016-10-13 16:58:25.235 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15345
2016-10-13 16:58:25.235 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 11671
2016-10-13 16:58:25.235 APP[1305:364048] PROPERTY: 15950
```

as you can see all info are not grouped and I need to put all on Array to save on UserDefaults, the problem is that when I tried to add on the array only add the last property, because always replace the other properties.

So I start using "loop for" to add every property to each index with this code.

```
NSMutableArray * MiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSInteger i=0;i<(unsigned long)self.properties.count;i++)
   {
     [MiArray setObject:property.propertyId atIndexedSubscript:i];
     NSLog(@"MiArray %@",MiArray);

   }
```

But does not work and start saving same property on each index and when finish start doing the same replacing with new property on each index again. like this:
I just put part of the code because is too long because the list is for each properties and are 190 properties:

```
2016-10-13 17:08:47.321 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    18382
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.322 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    18382,
    18382
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.322 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    18382,
    18382,
    18382
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.322 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.322 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.322 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.322 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382,
    18382
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.322 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    10250
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.323 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    10250,
    10250
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.323 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    10250,
    10250,
    10250
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.323 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.323 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.323 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250
)
2016-10-13 17:08:47.323 APP[1336:421695] MiArray (
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250,
    10250
)
```

I need some orientation to add all those properties to my array and I really don't know how to search about my problem.
I need to put all those properties to one array because I need to save all on UserDefaults, because when I tried first time only add last property and userDefaults only saves last property.

Comment: What is property? Is it properties[i]?